# Basic understanding javascript framework source

Tags: javascript

I'm green on programming js and I have a question:
I was reading `jQuery` and `Three.js` source code and I didn't found the reference to the javascript API. For example if you take a look at `jQuery` source you won't find the "d`ocument.getElementById`" word on the source so when you write "`$('#id')` the browser tells that it means "`document.getElementById`"... The same for `Three.js`: in the source there are methods called _gl.WHATEVER but I didn't find the gl.WHATEVER(a method of the webGL API)...

The question is how browser knows the proper name of the method if there's not an alias inside (and yet works!!!) for example `_gl = "gl";` (in three.js) or

in jQuery element = `document.getElementById("elementId");`
I hope you understand what I mean... and thank you in advanced!

Comment: Did you have a look at the minified source? You should _always_ look at the original source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

Comment: I found a document.getElementById. Wasn't very hard. https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery/master/src/core.js and https://raw.github.com/jquery/sizzle/master/sizzle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you were not looking in the proper place.

Here (developer's version) http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js you can find getElementById
and everything is nicely documented.

But in minified http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js for sure you will find nothing

I have not worked with tree.js, but I am sure that the same situation is there.

You might think about it this way.
If you will take a text file and then create archive in it and then look in the archive - most probably you will not find the words from you original text. (This is basically what minified version does)